# USB modem modules

Tags: networking, usb, network-interface

I found, that there are several options to setup internet connection
over USB:

- Use cdc_acm mode and transfer data using PPP protocol
- Use cdc_ncm mode. System will setup `wwan` network interface. Also it will provide serial interfaces, which I can use for sending AT commands, for example.
- Use cdc_ether mode, which setup `ether` network interface. I suppose in that mode USB modem is discovered as external ethernet card.

I still don't understand, why do we have so many modules to use USB modem? What are the main differences between cdc_ether and cdc_ncm?